# EF Linq Include multiple strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, include

So I'm trying to retrieve (one or more) children of some entities using EF Linq.
The strange thing is that this isn't working:

```
public static class DbSetExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IDbSet<T> dbSet, params string[] paths) where T : class
    {
        foreach (var path in paths)
            dbSet.Include(path: path);

        return dbSet;
    }
}

//Usage: dbSet<Company>().Include(paths: nameof(Company.Projects))
```

In this case, every child is empty...
But when I use this, it works:

```
dbSet.Include("Projects");
```

Does anyone know why? And what I could do to solve this?

> **Solution**

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, params string[] paths) where T : class
{
    foreach (var path in paths)
        queryable = queryable.Include(path: path);

    return queryable;
}
```

Comment: maybe dbSet = dbSet.Include("Projects"); can work? Because you returns a DbSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Include` doesn't actually change anything about `dbSet`. It returns a value, not modifies the object it's called on.

```
foreach(var path in paths)
{
    dbSet = dbSet.Include(path: path);
}
```

should work.

Comment: Note that for this to run without errors, `dbSet` should be `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: `IDbSet<T>` extends `IQueryable<T>`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Nice find on the IQueryable and providing a solution as well.

Comment: *IDbSet<T> extends IQueryable<T>*. So `IDbSet<T>` is more specific than `IQueryable<T>` and the result of `Include`, being `IQueryable<T>` can't be assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by itself, this:

```
dbSet.Include(path: path);
```

doesn't alter the state of the dbSet.

So when you are returning, the include is not "included".